# AngularJS Custom Directive sample not working

Tags: angularjs

I am getting an error when I execute below angular custom Directive sample.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var myMod = angular.module('RKdirectives', []);

myMod.directive('rkd1', function () {
return {
restrict: 'A',
link: function (scope, element) {

 element.mouseup(function (event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 });

 element.focus(function (event) {
 element.select();
 });
 }
 }
 });

 var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['RKdirectives']);

 var ctrl = function ($scope) {
 };

 myApp.controller('ctrl', ctrl);

 </script>

</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
<input type="text" rkd1 />
</body>
</html>
```

When I execute this sample in browser , I get , TypeError: undefined is not a function in console.

Please let me know what i am missing.

Comment: do you have jQuery on the page?

Comment: `element.mouseup` and `element.focus` are jQuery functions. Try including jQuery to the page before angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `element.mouseup` and `element.focus` which are jQuery functions. You need to include jQuery to the page:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
```

From [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery
>   function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to
>   Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."